# Run a cron job every second minute of every hour

Tags: cron

I have a cron job that i want to run every second minute of every hour.before i would just run it every minute like

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/cron.php
```

but i now need it to run every second minute of ever hour. How can this be done?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your operating system is [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/) you could use the `@every_second` for example:

```
@every_second  /var/www/html/cron.php
```

For other systems, this could work:

Somethinig every hour:

```
@hourly /var/www/html/cron.php
```

Or every 45 minutes:

```
*/45 * * * * /var/www/html/cron.php
```

From [man 5 crontab](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?crontab(5)):

```
       string          meaning
       ------          -------
       @reboot         Run once, at startup of cron.
       @yearly         Run once a year, "0 0 1 1 *".
       @annually       (same as @yearly)
       @monthly        Run once a month, "0 0 1 * *".
       @weekly         Run once a week, "0 0 * * 0".
       @daily          Run once a day, "0 0 * * *".
       @midnight       (same as @daily)
       @hourly         Run once an hour, "0 * * * *".
       @every_minute   Run once a minute, "*/1 * * * *".
       @every_second   Run once a second.
```

Also, check this a reference: https://crontab.guru/

In case the system you are using doesn't support the `@every_second` you could give a try to something like:

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/cron.php
* * * * * (sleep 30; /var/www/html/cron.php)
```

Basically, they run at the same time (every minute) but one will wait for 30 seconds before starting, so `/var/www/html/cron.php` will be called every 30 seconds.

Comment: Can i set a cron to run at exact hour of the day says at 2300hrs

Comment: 0 23 /var/www/html/cron.php ?

Comment: So at the dying minute of the day `59 23 * * * /path/to/your/command` will this run at 2359hrs

Answer (score 0):

The format for crontab is as follow

```
m h  dom mon dow   command
```

So you can do

```
0 * * * yourcommand
```

It will run every hour at 00 minutes

Comment: So i can run at every second minute of the hour like `02 * * * yourcommand` and every 45th minute of every hour  like `45 * * * yourcommand` ?

Comment: Ok. Say i need the cron task to run  between 2nd and 2:59 and the script takes more time to process that the timespace between 2nd and 3rd minute, what happens? is the script terminated?

Comment: No, it will run until it is finished. If it does not until the next cron run, it'll start again in a separated thread

Comment: I am curious, could you show the crontab for running a command every 45th minute and also for running a command every 45th minute of every hour?. That would clear a lot of doubt.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the only solution I could get working is:

```
2-59/* * * * *
```

Which translates to simple English as:

At every 60th minute from 2 through 59.

I barely know about cron syntax, so not sure if this is the only way or is at least one of the better ways.

Answer (score 0):

***Below code worked for me.***

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal




* * * * * while : ; do sleep 1 ;  php /var/www/html/code.php || break ; done
```

**It helps me a lot.**